# problema str int en python

Tags: python, typeerror, int, str

buenas es un codigo sencillo de un ejercicio pero no logro dar con el error que es el siguiente:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
      def cargaDeDatos():
      lista=[]
      nombreEquipo=input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")
      while nombreEquipo!="salir":
            puntajeTablaPosiciones=int(input("ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: "))
            golesAFavor=int(input("ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: "))
            nombreEquipo=input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")
            lista.append([nombreEquipo,puntajeTablaPosiciones,golesAFavor])

            print(lista)
            return lista

    def primeroYUltimo(lista):
        print(type(0))

        listaPrimero=[]
        listaUltimo=[]
        for i in lista:
    
            if i[0][2]>=0:
                listaPrimero=i
                primero=i[0][2]
            if i[0][2]<=999:
                listaUltimo=i
                ultimo=i[0][2]
    
       print("goles a favor equipo primera posicion:" , listaPrimero)
       print("goles a favor equipo ultima posicion:" , listaUltimo)
       return listaPrimero,listaUltimo

      lista=cargaDeDatos()
      primeroYUltimo(lista)`
```

muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudar
pd el i[0][2] es int

Comment: Te sobra el primer indice. Usa `if i[2]>=0:`

Comment: ya lo hice y me da el mismo error, no se porque me toma como lo de la lista, cuando le porngo comillas al 0  y al 999 lo ejecuta pero solo me toma el ultimo valor no el que quiero filtrar en cada caso

Answer (score 1):

**Análisis**

```
def cargaDeDatos():
    lista = []

    nombreEquipo = input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")
    while nombreEquipo != "salir":
        puntajeTablaPosiciones = int(input("ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: "))
        golesAFavor = int(input("ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: "))
        nombreEquipo = input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")
        lista.append([nombreEquipo, puntajeTablaPosiciones, golesAFavor])

        print(lista)
        return lista
```

Resulta que antes de agregar el equipo a la lista, pides el nombre del siguiente equipo, entonces los nombres te quedan corridos: el primer equipo figura con el nombre del segundo, etc.

Peor es que tienes un `return` dentro del ciclo; significa que sólo pides un equipo y retornas de inmediato.

**Solución**

```
def cargaDeDatos():
    lista = []
    
    nombreEquipo = input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")
    while nombreEquipo != "salir":
        puntajeTablaPosiciones = int(input("ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: "))
        golesAFavor = int(input("ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: "))
        lista.append([nombreEquipo, puntajeTablaPosiciones, golesAFavor])
        print(lista)
        nombreEquipo = input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")

    return lista
```

Movemos la petición del nuevo equipo al final del ciclo y sacamos el `return` afuera, para que se ejecute solo al terminar el ciclo.

produce:

```
ingrese nombre del equipo: Chile
ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: 10
ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: 5
[['Chile', 10, 5]]
ingrese nombre del equipo: Rangers
ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: 5
ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: 2
[['Chile', 10, 5], ['Rangers', 5, 2]]
ingrese nombre del equipo: salir
```

**Analisis II**

```
  def primeroYUltimo(lista):
        print(type(0))

        listaPrimero=[]
        listaUltimo=[]
        for i in lista:
    
            if i[0][2]>=0:
                listaPrimero=i
                primero=i[0][2]
            if i[0][2]<=999:
                listaUltimo=i
                ultimo=i[0][2]
    
       print("goles a favor equipo primera posicion:" , listaPrimero)
       print("goles a favor equipo ultima posicion:" , listaUltimo)
       return listaPrimero,listaUltimo
```

Primero, un problema de nomenclatura. Usar los nombres apropiados ayuda a entender mejor el programa. Entonces, no hablemos de `listaPrimero` por qe esa variable no contiene una lista.

Segundo, esto es Python y hay formas más compactas de lograrlo:

```
def primeroYUltimo(lista):

    tabla_ordenada = sorted(lista, key=lambda equipo: equipo[1])
    print(tabla_ordenada)

    print("goles a favor equipo primera posicion:", tabla_ordenada[-1][1])
    print("goles a favor equipo ultima posicion:", tabla_ordenada[0][1])
    return tabla_ordenada[-1][1], tabla_ordenada[0][1]
```

Recibida la lista con los equipos, la ordenamos empleando como criterio el segundo campo (posición en el campeonato). Esto nos devuelve una lista con los equipos en orden ascendente por su posición.

La lista es una lista de equipos (tuplas). El peor equipo está en al principio  y el mejor, al final. Eso son respectivamente `tabla_ordenada[0]` y `tabla_ordenada[-1]`. La posición está en el segundo elemento, que es `tabla_ordenada[0][1]`

Lo que nos interesa son los goles, que es segundo elemento. Entonces, `tabla_ordenada[0][2]`, etc.

#### Demo

```
def cargaDeDatos():
    lista = []

    nombreEquipo = input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")
    while nombreEquipo != "salir":
        puntajeTablaPosiciones = int(input("ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: "))
        golesAFavor = int(input("ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: "))
        lista.append([nombreEquipo, puntajeTablaPosiciones, golesAFavor])
        print(lista)
        nombreEquipo = input("ingrese nombre del equipo: ")

    return lista


def primeroYUltimo(lista):

    tabla_ordenada = sorted(lista, key=lambda equipo: equipo[1])
    print(tabla_ordenada)

    print("goles a favor equipo primera posicion:", tabla_ordenada[-1][2])
    print("goles a favor equipo ultima posicion:", tabla_ordenada[0][2])
    return tabla_ordenada[-1][1], tabla_ordenada[0][2]

lista = cargaDeDatos()
primeroYUltimo(lista)
```

produce:

```
ingrese nombre del equipo: Rangers
ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: 3
ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: 1
[['Rangers', 3, 1]]
ingrese nombre del equipo: Colo-Colo
ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: 9
ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: 6
[['Rangers', 3, 1], ['Colo-Colo', 9, 6]]
ingrese nombre del equipo: Chile
ingrese puntaje en la tabla de posiciones: 10
ingrese cantidad de goles a favor: 4
[['Rangers', 3, 1], ['Colo-Colo', 9, 6], ['Chile', 10, 4]]
ingrese nombre del equipo: salir
[['Rangers', 3, 1], ['Colo-Colo', 9, 6], ['Chile', 10, 4]]
goles a favor equipo primera posicion: 4
goles a favor equipo ultima posicion: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: te agradezco mucho,el codigo lo corregi en la primera parte pero tengo que hacerlo con esas herramientas que estan en el codigo (for, if, while). lo que me doy cuenta ahora es que esta bien tu interpretacion del ejercicio tengo que colocar los goles a favor teniendo en cuenta el puntaje del primero y el ultimo equipo con mayor y menor puntaje respectivamente.